# Why is $M\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + M\left(\frac{n}{4}\right) + \ldots + M\big(1\big) = O\big(M(n)\big)\,$?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, analysis-of-algorithms

We are given a sequence $M(n)$ and we know that $M(n) = O\left(n^2\right)$. Why does it follow that $M\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + M\left(\frac{n}{4}\right) + \ldots + M\big(1\big) = O\big(M(n)\big)\,$?

I need this to solve problem 0.4 in Dasgupta's book Algorithms. I couldn't figure it out myself and the internet was of no help either - I found two solutions but I couldn't understand either of them.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I don't believe this is true -- for example, what if $M(n)=1$? You might also need to use that $M(n)=\Omega(n)$.

Comment: @gst076923 I couldn't really figure out anything worth mentioning. I've tried finding an upper bound for this expression but I am clueless because M(n) could actually be any sequence that is asymptotically bounded by $n^2$. And I really didn't get any idea how to help myself with the asymptotic bound that was given.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut How could I prove it in that case?

Comment: Can you point me to the problem? I haven't found it [here](http://algorithmics.lsi.upc.edu/docs/Dasgupta-Papadimitriou-Vazirani.pdf), on page 18.

Comment: @Matija The sum is the the complexity of the algorithm for which we are determining the complexity in 0.4 e), so in that task I have to prove that the sum is asymptotically upper bounded by $M(n)$

Comment: I think that's a simple typo, respectively unfortunate wording. In part 0.4(d) they tell you to assume that $M(n)=\mathcal O(n^2)$, the school method for multiplication. While there is no error here, the school method for multiplication involves exactly $n^2-1$ additions for two $n$-bit numbers, i.e. $\Theta(n^2)$, which is basically what Carl was pointing to.

Answer (score 2):

$M(n/2) + M(n/4)+ \cdots + M(1) = O(n^2/4)+O(n^2/16)+O(n^2/64)+ \cdots $.

Because all the $O$ have the same constant (they come from the same estimate of the function $M$), you can factor them out like this (go back to the definition $\leq Cn^2$ if you want to see why).

$\cdots = O(n^2) (1/4 + 1/16 + 1/64 + \cdots) = O(n^2)$ because the factor is a convergent series.

I don't think you can get anything better, in particular $O(M(n))$, unless you assume stronger regularity estimates on $M$.

Comment: The problem does indeed provide $M(n)=n^2+\mathcal O(1)$. Nice solution!